# Python: Assert that all objects in a list have a specific attribute values

Tags: python, django

I am working for a web-app using django-1.6 where there will be application(s) coming in and going through various stages of scrutiny. On satisfying criteria(s), they get approved and promoted to the next stage or get deferred. I was testing the approval transition. And landed up in situation where I need to assert if approvable application(s) have their status changed to pending for the next stage. So, this is how I do it right now:

```
self.assertEqual('stage2.pending', stage1_approved_mentor_applications[0].status)
```

what I am looking for is something like

```
self.assertEqual('stage2.pending', stage1_approved_mentor_applications.status)
```

which would assure that all the objects in the list stage1_approved_mentor_applications have their status as 'stage2.pending'. One way would be to pass it to a function taking a list and returning True on all status being 'stage2.pending' and False if otherwise. This function will be called in assertTrue. Wondering if there's already a workaround for this that would save me from reinventing the wheel.

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about this:

```
for s in stage1_approved_mentor_applications:
   self.assertEqual('stage2.pending', s.status)
```

so you know what status is different

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
self.assertFalse(
    any(obj.status != 'stage2.pending' for obj in stage1_approved_mentor_applications)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.assertTrue(
    all([x is 'stage2.pending' for x in stage1_approved_mentor_applications]
))`

Comment: It Works! Boklucius..also thanks for the answer freakish and kharandziuk..Isn't there some assert that iterates internally...I mean I want to do away with writing the iteration myself...some inbuilt assert.